# What could be better message to any user in facebook?

Tags: error-message, messages, facebook

I tried to create a facebook account for my baby (2 years old). Facebook request to enter real birthday

**It is her real birthday**
I don't know also don't care  what is minimum age bar set by facebook to open account. In this forum, I want to know what could be good message for this case?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I wish I'd just comment on that.

Anyway, the message should be like this:

> "You must be at least 13 years old to have a Facebook account"

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it seems you are too little to join us...

You should be at least 13 years old to join Facebook.